# Zero price for first item in mini cart

Tags: magento-1.9, mini-cart

I created a controller to add configurable product to cart but when i try to reload the minicart dynamically using javascript or even refresh the page in product detail page it shows the wrong price and wrong color for the product, but when i go to /checkout/cart, the mini-cart shows the right product price and color. to load the minicart dynamically using javascript, i use the minicart block from controller like this:

```
 if ($this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart'))
  $minicart = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart')->toHtml();
```

here's the wrong minicart example after i add the product to the cart in product page details:

[image: wrong mini-cart]

and after i go to /checkout/cart, the mini cart shows the right price and product color:

[image: right mini-cart]

Comment: You'd post code of minicart block... it seems you're loading configurable product in first screenshot, and the simple product in the second

Comment: Have u found any solution for this issue?